# f.select showing Value in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the Following, however it will not show the current value when editing the record. What needs to change to correct this

```
 <%= f.select :name, options_for_select([["Select Name", ""], "James", "John", "Richard", "Mike", "Peter"]), :class => 'small-input' %>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use :

```
= f.select :your_field, options_for_select(array_list_of_possibilities, selected_value), :prompt => "select a name : "
```

Take a look at :
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Comment: <%=f.select :name, options_for_select([["James", "James"], ["John", "John"]], selected_value), :prompt => "select a name : "%>

Does Not Work

Comment: `= select_tag :name, options_for_select(["James", "John", "Richard", "Mike", "Peter"],"Mike")` or `= select_tag :name, options_for_select([["James",1], ["John",2], ["Richard",3], ["Mike",4], ["Peter",5]],["Mike",4])`